# Cypher Batch Update Taking Forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was doing a POC on publicly-available Twitter dataset for our project. I was able to create the Neo4j database for it using Michael Hunger's Batch Inserter utility, and it was relatively fast (It just took a 2h and 53 mins to finish). All in all there were
15,203,731 Nodes, with 2 properties (name, url)
256,147,121 Relationships, with 1 property

Now I created a Cypher query to update the Twitter database. I added a new property (Age) on the Node and a new property on the Relationship (FollowedSince) in the CSVs. Now things start to look bad. The query to update the relationship (see below) takes forever to run.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM {csvfile} AS row FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MATCH (u1:USER {name:row.`name:string:user`}), (u2:USER {name:row.`name:string:user2`})
MERGE (u1)-[r:Follows]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET r.Property=row.Property, r.FollowedSince=row.FollowedSince
ON MATCH SET r.Property=row.Property, r.FollowedSince=row.FollowedSince;
```

I already pre-created the index by running

```
CREATE INDEX ON :USER(name);
```

My neo4j property:

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
dump_configuration=false
cache_type=none
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=260M
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=260M
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=768M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=12G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=260M

node_auto_indexing=true
```

I'd like to know what should I do to speed up my Cypher query? As of this writing, it's more than an hour and a half have passed and my Relationship (10,000,747) still hasn't finished. The Node (15,203,731) that finished earlier clocked at 34 minutes which I think is way too long. (The Batch Inserter utility processed the whole Node in just 5 minutes!)

I did test my queries on a small dataset just to try it out first before tackling bigger dataset, and it did work.

My Neo4j lives on a server-grade machine, so hardware is not an issue here.

Any advice please? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know that it will help you at all, but I believe you could combine the `ON CREATE SET` and `ON MATCH SET` into a single `SET` since they both do the same thing

Comment: 1) How much RAM does that machine have? 2) Which OS are you running? 3) what are your `initmemory` and `maxmemory` setting in `neo4j-wrapper.conf` ?

Comment: My server has 32 GB of memory. 
initmemory and maxmemory are disabled in neo4j-wrapper.conf. I just accepted the default configuration out of the box. I just pass my own configuration to my app through a property file.

Comment: Forgot to add above, my OS is Centos 6.6

Comment: I'm also using Neo4j 2.1.6

Comment: Guys any updates on this, were you able to figure out what went wrong?